# getting packages into Ubuntu during Debian freeze

Tags: package-management

I am the developer of an application found in the Ubuntu repos. A few months ago I released a new version which I packaged and submitted to Debian. The  package was accepted and uploaded to experimental because Debian was and still is frozen for release. This package has not been picked up by 13.04 because Ubuntu imports from unstable which still has the old version.

How do I get my package into Ubuntu 13.04, given that Debian is frozen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed to request a package sync.

The information for how to do this is located here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SyncRequestProcess

I followed the recomendations there and used the requestsync commandline tools as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools
requestsync -d experimental widemargin
```

This raised a bug request on launchpad which can be seen here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/widemargin/+bug/1146015

The bug was fixed within 3 hours by Julian Taylor (jtaylor) who uploaded it to ubuntu 13.04

Julian Taylor you ROCK!!!

That is all.

Comment: Posting a problem and then posting your solution to a problem are the best questions! Great job! All up vote! :)